# It's time for a real difficult question

Tags: riddle, story

You enter a room. The doors close behind you, and you are locked in. You look around the room, and all there is in this empty, barren place is:

- 2 notepads
- Some writing on the wall
- A hammer

There is some writing on the notepad:

*This shady dude tried to sell this place to us for a strange $100. A room this size would normally cost 10 grand... The shady dude said, "I decided to add reinforced walls, roof, and floor. I also decided to make the door with a 12 digit code, also reinforced, to prevent anyone from getting inside." Feeling sketchy, We denied the offer. I'll just leave this notepad in here for anyone else who tried to buy this.*

You take a look at the other notepad:

*So this guy sold this place to me for $100 (Great deal!), a nice big room which offers a large amount of space. I **just** started to unpack the first box. This notepad, the tape measure, and my trusty hammer just came out, when all of a sudden, the moving van drove off with the rest of my stuff! My phone, my wallet, all my furniture and food, everything was in there... That van driver must have some real nerve to steal from me... I'm going to walk back to my mother's house (hopefully she'll let me stay there), get a new phone, and hopefully my life will end up just fine...*

The writing on the wall showed:

**1 + 1 = 3**

**2 + 2 = 6**

**3 + 3 = 9**

*That's creepy...*, you think.

The tape measure had its numbers all mixed up and faded. Instead of showing 1 feet, 2 feet, 3 feet, it showed 3 feet, 6 feet, 9 feet...

The hammer was rusty, the head was about to fall off.

You thought, how will I ever get out?

Comment: This took a dark turn with the second notepad. :O

Comment: so here 4+4 = 12?

Comment: One thing, who would put food in a moving truck? (other than this person)

Comment: An adventurous idea:  The keypad would be extra big (don't know why) and take the end of the hammer and smash it up and leave. The writing and stuff could be red herring.

Comment: I know! You escape by... figuring out the puzzle.

Comment: Can you give any hint?

Comment: Sorry, no hints; this puzzle is meant to be difficult. Keep thinking guys! You'll come up with the answer eventually.

Comment: @BenDover Is there any knowledge tag needed for this puzzle or all what is needed is inside the story?

Answer (score 3):

Probably not the answer you're looking for, and I will re-work it at some point; however, I would get out by:

> Utilizing the 12 digit code lock on the door. I would enter the code 1-1-3-2-2-6-3-3-9-3-6-9.

My reasoning:

> The numbers that are given in order, not just the mathematical ones, but the nice ***instead it showed 3 feet, 6 feet, 9 feet***.

Comment: GAH, a simple oversight; I can remove that last portion then! LOL

Comment: That was a pretty good guess, but still not right.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess but I think it's way to simple to be the answer.

> enter 441255156618

Reasoning

> it's the following sequence to the writing on the wall. 4+4=12 5+5=15 6+6=18

Answer (score 2):

> The tape measure had its numbers all mixed up and faded. Instead of
> showing 1 feet, 2 feet, 3 feet, it showed 3 feet, 6 feet, 9 feet...

Hate to point it out, but 3, 6 and 9 are not "mixed up". They are still in an increasing order. Some measuring tapes actually have feet mentioned on them in 3-unit increments to make it easier for its user to count towards a yard. So the OP might consider rephrasing that sentence in the puzzle.
(Mine should have been a comment but it needs site reputation that my account lacks at the moment.)

Coming to the answers...

## 1: You thought, how will I ever get out?

> Well, you only thought. You did not yet decide to get out.

## 2: If you have decided to get out:

> you could check if the door is actually "locked". Maybe it just needs a push of the handle/knob to open so there's no need to start worrying about a code.

## 3: If the door is actually locked and you need to figure out a code,

> there might be hints available at 3 feet, 6 feet, 9 feet from the measuring tape (or from the door; or from the writing on the wall) in the room that could help determine the code.

Comment: All I'll say is this: You got the closest to the answer. Keep going!

Answer (score -2):

> The door code is 369 369 369 369.

Comment: Okay, not wanting to be a drag or anything, but... Did you really think this through m8?